# How to draw UML diagrams using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, uml

What is the version of Eclipse that can be used to draw the UML diagrams. That is what is the version of Java with which the tools to draw UML diagrams comes along with it.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988384/eclipse-uml-plugin or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse or any other hit you get when searching for "[eclipse] uml"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The probably best choice at the moment is the [Papyrus](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/) component in Eclipse Indigo. The exact Java version doesn't play a big role in that, you just need to be able to run Eclipse.

Comment: Papyrus and Topcased are good choice for UML but not for Java because you need to create a modeling project which is not compatible with a java/jee nature project.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse itself maintains a list of Eclipse plug-ins/tools to create UML models compatible with the official Eclipse MDT-UML2 Eclipse project. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2-Tool-Compatibility

Answer (score 0):

The only professional quality tool which allows the use of java and UML is Omondo but it is really very very expensive. Ridiculous pricing !!

Other plugins are only focus on UML but no real Java extensions. eUML could have been a good free candidate but it seems the tool has been stopped http://www.soyatec.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=955

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways is to use **PlantUML** plugin for eclipse.
It is an open source software and is really simple to use.

See the documentation [here](http://plantuml.com/eclipse)!

Answer (score -1):

try to install this plugin in eclipse

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/umlet-uml-tool-fast-uml-diagrams

it's easy to use.

Comment: The download page says - "This installation is distributed with the AVG Toolbar. You can decline to install it. AVG add-on supports IE, Firefox and Chrome. It shall change the user home page and default search in IE, Firefox and Chrome, in the event you select such options."  I hate software that modifies my home page and search!